# Temperature control during 1st phase fermentation

Tags: fermentation, temperature, temperature-control, stuck-fermentation, primary-fermentation

I am having some issues keeping the temperature controlled. I live in SE QLD and the daily ambient temperature has been 23 degrees C down to 11C. I've been advised not to let the wort drop below 18C but it has been lower, about 15C with a high of about 22C.
I would like to know
        1 What are the ill affects of this (other than the yeast becoming inactive)
2 If I leave it a bit longer and get the temperature regulated (towels and a heat pad) Would I  be ok to leave it for a couple of weeks and then check the hydrometer before bottling?
         Thanks

Comment: What yeast are you using?

Comment: I have just used the yeast packs included in the cans of Morgans brew kits.

Comment: Reading the stockist website I am fairly sure that I am using Saccharomyces Cerevisiae http://morgansbrewing.com.au/products/hops-yeast/. It seems to be the standard one that they supply.

Comment: @Snarf, WOW, I do not trust that site's yeast description at all. They say its a "Lager Yeast", but identify it as Sach. Cerevisiae (lager yeasts is actually Sach. Pastorianus), and they say to ferment it ideally at 22C/71F and up to 32C/89F, which is FAR outside the temp range for all lager yeast anyway. For your next batch, order some dry yeast from Fermentis instead.

Answer (score 1):

Idiot-proofing the fermentation temperatures has been a bit of a peeve of mine right now, as I use a family member's basement as a brewery and I have little control of the ambient room temperature.

The DIY solution I am working on uses a $15 digital thermostat/controller with a sinkable probe from [Ebay](http://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_odkw=12V%2F110V%2F220V%20Digital%20LCD%20Thermostat%20Temperature%20Regulator%20Controller%20Aquarium&_from=R40&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X12V%2F110V%2F220V%20Digital%20LCD%20Thermostat%20Temperature%20Regulator&_nkw=12V%2F110V%2F220V%20Digital%20LCD%20Thermostat%20Temperature%20Regulator&_sacat=0) to switch on/off a typical brewing heat belt (a FermWrap would be better if I had one) at set temperature thresholds.

Follow this video tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7I-iwFLykxs), plug in and install the heat belt and sterilize/sink the probe into the beer.

I have seen people use this system to activate a space heater for entire brew rooms, which might be economical if I wasn't using an entire basement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to extend the fermentation time, as cold will slow down the yeast's ability to reproduce and ferment.  Your best bet is to get a temperature controller (e.g. [STC-1000](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00862G3TQ) or [Johnson digital controller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00368D6JA)) and accompany that with your heat pad or a purpose built [FermWrap](http://morebeer.com/products/fermwrap-heater.html) from MoreBeer.

Worst case, you don't attenuate all the way, and then when you bottle, you risk the yeast kicking back into action and over-carbonating your bottles with dangerous consequences.  Less pessimistic would be to have them drop off too early and you'd have a sweeter than normal beer.  Other side effects include flavor production depending on the yeast used.  Some yeast produce certain flavor compounds at certain temperatures.  Take a typical Hefeweizen yeast such as [WLP300](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp300-hefeweizen-ale-yeast).  They tend to produce more clove flavor at below-optimal temperatures, and banana at above-optimal temperatures.  To balance them, you would need to ensure proper fermentation temperature.

Also, if you can steady the temperature with heating & cooling, your temperatures sound like they'd do well for lagers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as bad as you think. Remember, you have 20 l of beer. It takes time to warm it up and time to cool, so temperature fluctuations in the fermenter will be smoothed. I would wrap the fermenter in a blanket and leave like that for the normal fermentation time.